# Encrypt files on harddrive with double encryption

Tags: encryption, keys, multiple-encryption

So I've been stuck on this question for a very long time.

How do you use double encryption to encrypt a hard disk so that all of the following conditions are met:

1. All data on the hard disk is encrypted.
2. There are multiple users and each user has his own key to make the harddisk readable/writable. Think for example of a normal user and the administrator. (everyone can access any file though, no permissions needed)
3. If a user forgets his key, a new key can be generated for him, with which he simply has access to the stored data.

Comment: What files are encrypted? Only inf user home dir or all directories on all mounted drives?

Comment: for simplicity, we are just talking about .txt files which are all encrypted @mentallurg

Comment: I wouldn't call it *simplicity*. It is simple to encrypt the whole drive. But dealing with separate files is more complex. Also, the title of your question contradicts to your statement that your want to process separate files only. Please change the title and the text of the question, so that everyone understands that correctly.

Comment: @mentallurg im sorry im new to encrypting, will change it. Do you have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: First update the question. Then we will see what are you actually asking.

Comment: @mentallurg i changed the title, the question stays the same

Comment: If the full disk encrypted than the root/administrator can enable all users to read/write. VeraCrypt - like many disk encryption utilities - provides multiple key slots to that each can be given to a user and all can mount. Is this enough? That is not related to Cryptography, rather superuser...

Comment: @Cryptofan12: In such formulation the question sound different. Please look at this one: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35616/multi-key-encryption.

Comment: @kelalaka: If we are talking about the whole drive, then yes, it should be moved to the Superuse SE. But if it is about multi key encryption, it has much bigger part of cryptography, but well, may be even then it is closer to the Superuser SE.

Comment: @mentallurg yes multi-key belongs here.